# Books to go Along with Dummit & Foote

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I’m signed up for a first-year grad algebra class and the assigned textbook is Dummit & Foote. So I’m looking for another book or two that would go good with D&F.

Some qualities I’m looking for: (0) Begins with groups or categories (or semigroups or monoids), (1) Strong treatment of groups and representations of finite groups, (2) Strong treatment of noncommutative rings, (3) Doesn’t shy away from category theory, and (4) Covers some homological algebra.

Bonus points if it talks about Lie algebras and k-theory.

I’m not opposed to older or terse prose.

Oh, and I’m not a fan of Hungerford’s “Algebra.”

Edit: I am not looking for a category theory book. Nor am I looking for a book which covers everything completely through category theory. But I’d like it covered.

Comment: What don’t you like about those last two?

Comment: Hungerford feels terribly dry to me. I don’t know why since I don’t find Lang dry. I don’t like that rotman starts with commutative rings. That’s pretty much my only complaint there.

Comment: You want a book that covers category theory, but doesn't feel dry? (also since you mention Lang, what's wrong with Lang?)

Comment: Most of those topics are really better addressed *after* your first-year grad algebra class.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with Lang whatsoever. I just didn’t know if people thought something like Jacobson, MacLane & Birkhoff, or Aluffi would be better. Or something which I’ve never heard of. On second thought, I’d even give Rotman another chance if people recommend it (I’ll make an edit). And to clarify, I don’t want a category theory book. I want an algebra book which isn’t afraid to use category theory or phrase things in the language of category theory.

Answer (score 3):

I would consider [*Algebra: Chapter 0*](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/6829004-algebra) by Aluffi, although it doesn’t satisfy all your requirements. The voice of the text is light and conversational, and Aluffi does give some allusions to analogies in other interesting categories at times (e.g. category of smooth manifolds).

The book’s language is highly categorical — Chapter I is entirely dedicated to introducing categories, and the categorical theory develops as the algebraic does.

Groups are well-represented, with Chapter II and IV fully dedicated to group theory, although (as Aluffi points out in the introduction) any representation theory is “missing altogether.”

While I wouldn’t say that noncommutative rings are *strongly* treated, they are certainly treated well. Chapter IX focuses fully on homological algebra.